# weird same output when using sudo command [ lp_bool(yesm): value is not boolean! ]

Tags: sudo

Whenever I am using `sudo` (followed by other command) I am getting same error again and again, here it is:

```
lp_bool(yesm): value is not boolean!
```

for example, `sudo <some command>`

```
lp_bool(yesm): value is not boolean!
<regular output of that command>
```

Comment: Is this just with samba-related commands? What do you get from running `sudo -v`?

Comment: I didn't change anything; did you?

Comment: @JeffSchaller getting same error with `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @JeffSchaller should I try `-v` option with every command?

Comment: Looks like it could be a configuration typo somewhere; try sudoers and pam

Comment: Have you found any reference to "yesm", following Gilles' suggestion?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Nope, I just followed Gilles method and it worked :)

Comment: Gilles' post was just a pointer to help find the actual issue -- unless running "sudo find ..." mysteriously fixed the problem, can you elaborate as to what the fix was, for future readers?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have answer my solution. BUT why the error in Samba config file was pointed by `sudo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles), from whom I got the clue. What I did is as follows:

after running `sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep yesm {} +` I found `yesm` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

```
pam password change = yesm
```

Like it said in the error it is supposed to be a boolean so it can be either `yes` or `no`. After going through documentation of Samba `yes` is what I wanted. After editing it to `yes` I restarted Samba server and after that I didn't got that error

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a configuration file where `yesm` is written but `yes` or `no` is expected. Look for a file containing `yesm` under `/etc`:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep yesm {} +
```

Apparently the `lp_bool` message comes from Samba, so the error is probably in a Samba-related configuration file.